# Random number generation with weibull distribution in java

Tags: java, random, distribution, weibull

I want to generate random number from a weibull distribution with given shape and scale factor. I used the below code but the values generated are always close to beta. How to change the range of values?

```
public double weibull(double eta, double beta)              
{               
    RandomGenerator rg = new JDKRandomGenerator();
    WeibullDistribution g= new WeibullDistribution(rg, eta, beta, WeibullDistribution.DEFAULT_INVERSE_ABSOLUTE_ACCURACY);
    return g.sample();
}
```

Comment: Is `WeibullDistribution` from the apache commons lib?

Answer (score 1):

If this is the `WeibullDistribution` from the Apache commons distribution, the second and third arguments to the constructor you used are a shape parameter and a scale parameter, respectively.  Values of the shape parameter above 2 or so will tend to give outcomes close to the scale parameter.  If you don't want that, change the shape parameter.

Please note that you should **not** be constructing a new `rg` and new `WeibullDistribution` object each time you invoke your method.  Make both of those `static` and re-use them.